# Might GC.Collect() be warranted in this particular case?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

**Disclaimer**: Yes, I know that the general answer to whether or not to use GC.Collect() is a resounding "NO!". This is the first time in several years of programming that I ever consider using it at all.

Well then, here's the situation: We have developed a C# scripting tool based on the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting libraries` (v3.6.0). It's a Winform GUI with editor etc., not unlike others out there. We use it for the validation of integrated circuits, meaning that its primary task is interfacing lab equipment such as power supplies, pattern generators, meters and the like. For the communication to said instruments we predominantly rely on National Instrument's VISA framework, albeit not exclusively. Some devices are controlled directly via DLLs from their respective manufacturers. In general, this system is working beautifully and by now it is successfully used by quite a lot of design engineers who do not know the first thing about the intricacies of .NET and C#.

At this point I should explain that the user can simply write a method (i.e. on "top-level") and then execute it. The Roslyn-part behind this is that the input is fed to `CSharpScript.Create()` and then compiled. The execution of a method is done via `Script.ContinueWith("method name")`. Inside of such a method the user can construct an object like, say, `new VISA("connection string")`, which connects to the device and then communicate with the device via this object. Nothing forces him or her to care about disposing the object (i.e. closing the connection).

**Now, the problem is this**: recently, very sporadic crashes of the GUI application have occurred with no feedback at all from the system - the form just closes and that's it. By trial-and-error we are currently 99% sure that if all connection objects are explicitely disposed within a method, the crashes do not occur. So, rewriting the method to something like this fixes the problem:

```
using(var device = new VISA("connection string"))
{
    device.Query("IDN?");
}
```

The reason why I look into the GC's direction at all is that there is no discernible correlation to any actions from the user. The guys might run such methods for an hour without a problem and then, when scrolling in the editor, when no method is currently being executed, the GUI closes without comment. And that's why I'd like to get some input from people more knowledgeable about Roslyn and the GC:

1. Are there known issues with this scripting library and GC? (I would very much assume that there aren't)
2. Since the explicit disposal of objects seem to prevent the issue, might this be one of the extremely scarce situations where the use of `GC.Collect()` might be warranted? (admittedly, I could not yet test whether that also prevents the problem thanks to of home office)
3. Any ideas what can cause a .NET application to crash without any kind of feedback and how to obtain more information about such a crash? (the scripting engine is a separate DLL, as are the device drivers; the GUI only handles the graphics)

I am fully aware that this is a rather vague description of the problem with very little source code. This is due to the fact that the application comprises of quite a lot of source code and I have no idea what might be relevant here. Also, all namespaces in the above text refer to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`, except for `VISA`, which is self-defined. Obviously, I will gladly answer any follow-up questions for getting to the bottom of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Any ideas what can cause a .NET application to crash without any kind of feedback and how to obtain more information about such a crash?*" -- an unhandled exception will do this, as simple as that. Check the windows event log, under Windows Logs -> Application. There are normally 2 Error entries for .NET-related crashes: one's pretty yseless, and one has the stack trace in

Comment: That's correct, get the stack trace first and then we'll talk -- if it's even necessary. My bet is either on memory corruption (you mentioned native components) or objects being disposed early (keep better track of your objects). Or you're running out of 32-bit address space, but if you're writing 32-bit code in C# you're doing it wrong on such a fundamental level as to be virtually hopeless.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the problem might be in the `VISA` finalizer: if it's properly disposed then the finalizer won't run, but if it's left to the GC to finalize, you get a crash. In this case, calling `GC.Collect()` will just make it crash faster, since you'll be calling the finalizer sooner! That might not be the case, but based on the digging you've done it's where I'd look. Also get crash logs: look in the event log, attach a logging handler to `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, configure Windows to create a full dump / minidump on crash, etc

Comment: But... you already know how to fix the problem... by properly disposing of objects. `GC.Collect` doesn't dispose anything; it finalizes. So your suggestion is like trying to hammer in a nail with a drill - when there is a screwhole, a screw, and screwdriver right next to you.

Comment: Well, if you call "Doctor it hurts when I poke it / Stop poking it then" a "solution". I'd argue that your application shouldn't crash even if a finalizer does end up being called...

Comment: @Blindy OP may not have a choice - a lot of DLLs are ancient and terrible and stuck in x86-land, and if you want to call them from .NET you have to build your .NET app as x86.

Comment: Also, as others have noted above, the fact that your app apparently has zero logging is **seriously** concerning. It seems you're trying to implement a (demonstrably poor, if not completely incorrect/useless) "solution" without understanding the symptoms - that's a recipe for even more pain.

Comment: Also, if you've found a way to make it stop crashing, you've also found a way to make it crash **more**. If you can make it crash inside a debugger, you're probably in a good place to figure out what's wrong

Comment: @IanKemp, unfortunately excuses don't matter for much. He's using run-time compilation which has no way of removing compiled code from memory, it will only increase. You can't do that in 32-bit with the way the GC works (only contiguous chunks of memory) and not expect problems eventually. And of course you can deal with 32-bit libraries, write proxies and talk to them over UDP or shared memory. As a bonus, you isolate possible native memory corruption to external processes!

Comment: Very well, sound advice. I am indeed aware that the actual source of the crashes should be found and only then a sensible solution should be applied. And you all have convincingly established that GC won't be it. I will try to gather the logs from this person's computer and see if there's something there.
Btw, logging via log4net is in fact part of the application. Maybe I misunderstood you there @Ian Kemp, but if you would care to educate me what kind of logging that is part of the application itself could log a crash of said application?

Comment: @jber Attach logging handlers to things like `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.UnhandledException` (for UWP, other frameworks have similar)

Comment: Alright, we got 50% of it. `Application.UnhandledException` is logged. There was nothing there.

Comment: Interesting... That should cover all mananged exceptions. The event log, getting it to crash in a debugger, and getting Windows to record a crash dump would be my first 3 ports of call, in that order. And sanity-check the `VISA` finalizer of course

Comment: E.g. if you've discovered that creating a `VISA` and then not disposing it could cause the crashes, make millions of them in a loop and don't dispose them. Throw in a `GC.Collect()` to see if it helps trigger the crash sooner.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got that. I am really off the GC-direction because something in the application obviously misbehaves in its own right. I'd rather find that first and the steps you proposed sound promising in that regard. By now, the title is very wrong with respect to the actual issue & discussion. Is there some procedure for coping with that on SO?

Comment: I think your question stands as a valid question: your understanding of the situation has evolved through the discussion, but that's normal for debugging issues. Feel free to self-answer if you feel you can add something which might help future readers, otherwise leave it be or self-close (someone may come along and close it anyway). If you've got follow-up questions based on your improved understanding or further discoveries, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I will post an update in the original description once I have zeroed in on the actual issue. Yet this won't be until next week at earliest as I am stuck at home.

Comment: (By self-answer I mean post an actual answer, and accept it. That's a valid thing to do if you've discovered the answer to your own question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Short answer**: No. It's not only not warranted, it's completely missing the actual issue.

**Further explanation**: @canton7 instantly hit the nail on the head when writing

> I'd argue that your application shouldn't crash even if a finalizer does end up being called

The root issue hid inside a 3rd party DLL in form of an, at the very least, suboptimal implementation of IDisposable. Once I zoomed in on that, it was rather easy to produce a workaround for that.

My original question is so very misguided that I'd like to state the one that I *should* have asked:
**How do I trace a crash of my C# application when my application's logging does not show anything?**
This question has been answered comprehensively in a number of posts. In my case, the crash could be seen in the Windows event log.